# AspectJ Gradle plugin issue

Tags: java, gradle, aop

I have project A which uses aspectj (without spring) and I need to add project A dependency in project B(which is gradle based).

For maven based project, I am able make aspects work by adding project A dependency and aspectj-maven-plugin

But for gradle based project B, aspects are not working by adding project A dependency.

Can anyone help me with this?

I am using Gradle 7.4.2 version

I tried with org.aspectj.aspectj plugin but getting below error

```
Plugin [id: 'org.aspectj.aspectj', version: '1.9.5'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.aspectj.aspectj:org.aspectj.aspectj.gradle.plugin:1.9.5')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo
```

```java
maven {
    url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
}
```

I don't see org.aspectj.aspectj in gradle repository, but still same

Edit:

Gradle

```java
plugins {
  id 'org.aspectj.aspectj' version '1.9.5'
}

aspectj {
  aspectPath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

// adding project A as a dependency

dependencies {
  implementation project(':projectA')
}

dependencies {
  runtime 'org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.5'
}
```

Comment: Hi, please update your question to include the Gradle build scripts, and any error messages or console logs about the problem you are trying to resolve.

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Comment: Edited with build script snippet and error

Answer (score 1):

> ```java
> plugins {
>   id 'org.aspectj.aspectj' version '1.9.5'
> }
> ```

Well, you cannot simply invent non-existent Gradle plugin names and expect them to magically work. The error message explains that, too.

How about using the [Freefair AspectJ](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/current/reference/#_aspectj_plugins) plugin collection instead?

Comment: I tried with that as well, but looks like it is not maintained or it does not support Gradle 7

Comment: I am a Maven user, not a Gradle user. But last time I tried those plugins in order to help others here, they worked. About Gradle 7, I cannot say anything. Why would it not work? But even if it does not, what forces you to use Gradle 7? Besides, "I tried" does not qualify as a reproducible problem description. Why are you ignoring my advice to provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Where is your GitHub project reproducing your problem? Like this, neither are you going to find a lot of friends here, nor are you going to be able to solve your problems.